# Issue with allowing only one checkbox to ever be checked and controlling the class of the parent label based on that

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

**UPDATE:**

I fixed one of the issues, I had a typo in my class name spelling... silly mistake!

**The last issue** is that one *MUST* always be checked, so basically they cannot ever uncheck one that is already checked, unless selecting another option.

---

I have been trying to solve an issue with checkboxes and only allowing one to be selected at any one time.

Basically, I want:

- only one checkbox to be allowed to be selected at any one time
- if a checkbox is checked, its parent label should have a class of "checked-checkbox-parent" and the other checkboxes parents should remove that class (since only one checkbox should be selected, only its parent should ever have that class naturally)
- One checkbox will always be selected by default (dependant on the users current subscription), this will be controlled from the database, however, to track that, whatever their subscription type, the parent label of that subscription will have a class of "checked-checkbox-parent" and that checkbox will have a prop of ':checked'.

**Relevant code below:**

```js
var $boxes = $('#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label input[type="checkbox"]');

$boxes.on('click', function(e) {
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    var boxGroup = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    $(boxGroup)
      .prop("checked", false)
      .parent()
      .removeClass('checked-checkbox-parent');
    $box
      .prop("checked", true)
      .parent()
      .addClass('checked-checkbox-parent');
  } else {
    $box
      .prop("checked", false)
      .parent()
      .removeClass('checked-checkbox-parent');
  }
});
```

```css
.profile-edit-btn {
  color: #C99C49;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.modal .modal-dialog .modal-content {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: "museo500";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header button {
  color: white;
  font-family: "museo500";
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
.modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body {
  background: #F6F6F6;
  color: black;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form .btn-success {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: auto;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label,
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form input {
  width: 100%;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label {
  display: block;
  background: #C99C49;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label.checked-checkbox-parent {
  background: black;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "museo500";
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label span:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-family: "museo300";
  font-weight: normal;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form .confirmation-para {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "museo500";
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form input[type="password"] {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "museo500";
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="profile-edit-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-details-modal">Open Modal</a>


<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="my-details-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Update your membership</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <label for="one-month">
            <input id="one-month" name="profile-modal-check" type="checkbox">
            <span>Monthly</span>
            <span class="pull-right">(£30/case)</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </label>
          <label for="three-month">
            <input id="three-month" name="profile-modal-check" type="checkbox">
            <span>3 Months</span>
            <span class="pull-right">(£29/case)</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </label>
          <label for="six-month">
            <input id="six-month" name="profile-modal-check" type="checkbox">
            <span>6 Months</span>
            <span class="pull-right">(£28/case)</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </label>
          <label for="twelve-month">
            <input id="twelve-month" name="profile-modal-check" type="checkbox">
            <span>12 Months</span>
            <span class="pull-right">(£27/case)</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </label>
          <p class="confirmation-para">Enter your password to confirm</p>
          <input type="password" name="confirmation-password" placeholder="password">
          <input type="sumbit" value="confirm" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
        </form>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

If you have any questions, please comment below, I hope everything is clear enough though.

Comment: Consider using radio inputs instead of checkboxes.

Comment: because the project specifies checkboxes and when I asked to use radios instead, I was told no.

Comment: Can you decribe your issue in detail?

Comment: I would still use radios. Maybe I would hide them and display fake background images of checkboxes, but radios seem the way to go.

Comment: I fixed one of the issues, I had a typo in my class name spelling... silly mistake! The last issue is that one MUST always be checked, so basically they cannot ever uncheck one that is already checked, they can only ever select another option.

Comment: You have to place issues description into **the question**, not comment

Comment: inserted as an update.

Comment: Your code has many superfluous parts. For instance you select all needed checkboxes (`$boxes`) and then select them again (`boxGroup`) inside event handler. Why? You can use `$boxes` variable which already stores exactly the collection you needed.

Comment: Good point, I suppose, however, atleast that part is working just now, as you can see in my update, I have one issue still outstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has many superfluous parts. For instance you select all needed checkboxes (`$boxes`) and then select them again (`boxGroup`) inside event handler. Why? You can use `$boxes` variable which already stores exactly the collection you needed.

Furthermore you have to listen for [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event, not `click`.

> For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired
>   immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse.

In this case you don't need to check if `this` element is checked.

So the code should be noticeably simplified.

In event handler you only need to set "disabled state" props/classes for all elements, then set "enabled state" props/classes for the checked element.

```
var $boxes = $('#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label input[type="checkbox"]');
$boxes.on('change', function(e) {
    $boxes.prop("checked", false)
    .parent().removeClass('checked-checkbox-parent');
    $(this).prop("checked", true)
    .parent().addClass('checked-checkbox-parent');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a while of thinking and refactoring, this is what I ended up with, it works and might not be the "cleanest" way, but it does exactly what is required as far as I can see.

- One checkbox will always be selected
- No box that is already checked can be unchecked without another option being selected
- the classes swap as expected due to an update on my typo

See comments I made in the code for more information/to see my thought process while programming this earlier.

```js
//target all the checkboxes for membership type
var $boxes = $('#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label input[type="checkbox"]');

//loop over each one and find the one that is to be checked at the start (determined by the users selected current subscription) and add the checked "state" to it
$boxes.each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
    $(this)
      .prop("checked", true)
      .parent()
      .addClass('checked-checkbox-parent');
  }
});

//when any of the boxes are clicked
$boxes.on('click', function(e) {
  //target the box being clicked on
  var $box = $(this);
  //if it is checked
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    //target all the checkboxes and reset their checked state to false
    $boxes
      .prop("checked", false)
      .parent()
      .removeClass('checked-checkbox-parent');
    //then select the current box being selected and set its checked state to true, thus only one box can ever be checked and one must always be checked.
    $box
      .prop("checked", true)
      .parent()
      .addClass('checked-checkbox-parent');
  }
});
```

```css
.profile-edit-btn {
  color: #C99C49;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.modal .modal-dialog .modal-content {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: "museo500";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header button {
  color: white;
  font-family: "museo500";
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
.modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body {
  background: #F6F6F6;
  color: black;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form .btn-success {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: auto;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label,
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form input {
  width: 100%;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label {
  display: block;
  background: #C99C49;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label.checked-checkbox-parent {
  background: black;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "museo500";
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form label span:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-family: "museo300";
  font-weight: normal;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form .confirmation-para {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "museo500";
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#my-details-modal .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body form input[type="password"] {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "museo500";
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="profile-edit-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-details-modal">Open Modal</a>


<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="my-details-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Update your membership</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <label for="one-month">
            <input id="one-month" name="profile-modal-check" type="checkbox" checked>
            <span>Monthly</span>
            <span class="pull-right">(£30/case)</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </label>
          <label for="three-month">
            <input id="three-month" name="profile-modal-check" type="checkbox">
            <span>3 Months</span>
            <span class="pull-right">(£29/case)</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </label>
          <label for="six-month">
            <input id="six-month" name="profile-modal-check" type="checkbox">
            <span>6 Months</span>
            <span class="pull-right">(£28/case)</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </label>
          <label for="twelve-month">
            <input id="twelve-month" name="profile-modal-check" type="checkbox">
            <span>12 Months</span>
            <span class="pull-right">(£27/case)</span>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </label>
          <p class="confirmation-para">Enter your password to confirm</p>
          <input type="password" name="confirmation-password" placeholder="password">
          <input type="sumbit" value="confirm" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
        </form>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```